# Replace text in google preferences file

Tags: json, powershell

Our organisation is moving to chrome as the default browser.

The problem is, its already on most of the fleet and custom language settings are set to en-US. I need some way to modify it to be en-AU.

I initially used fart.exe and replaced all instances of en-US with en-AU but when chrome re-launched it didnt like the format.

What i am basically trying to do is replace:

```
"intl":{"accept_languages":"en-US,en-AU,en-GB,en","selected_languages":"en-US,en-AU,en-GB,en"}
```

with

```
"intl":{"accept_languages":"en-AU","selected_languages":"en-AU"}
```

The problem is the text after "accept_languages": could be any combination of country locale settings.

I'm stumped. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Looks like the file is in JSON format. You can read it into an object graph with [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json), manipulate that object graph, then re-convert to JSON with [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) and save.

Comment: If you don't care about the languages just replace them all `"[^"]+?"` with the one you want. `"intl":{"accept_languages":"[^"]+?","selected_languages":"[^"]+?"}`. replacec with `"intl":{"accept_languages":"en-AU","selected_languages":"en-AU"}`

Comment: @user3783243 thanks for that. I came up with this. Seems to make the modifications:            $FilePath = "C:\Temp\Preferences"
(Get-Content -Raw $FilePath) -replace '"intl":{"accept_languages":"[^"]+?","selected_languages":"[^"]+?"}.' , '"intl":{"accept_languages":"en-AU","selected_languages":"en-AU"},' | Out-File $FilePath -Encoding UTF8

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `regex` in this case, you can use [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.2) to update it:

```bash
$json = @'
{
    "intl": {
        "accept_languages": "en-US,en-AU,en-GB,en",
        "selected_languages": "en-US,en-AU,en-GB,en"
    }
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json

$json.intl.'accept_languages' = 'en-AU'
$json.intl.'selected_languages' = 'en-AU'

$json | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File path\to\json.json -Encoding utf8
```

In the example above, `$json | ConvertTo-Json` would yield a Json like this one:

```
{
  "intl": {
    "accept_languages": "en-AU",
    "selected_languages": "en-AU"
  }
}
```

---

**Note**, the default encoding of the file seems to be `ANSI`, in this case `-Encoding Default` should work. Thanks [@Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70104876/replace-text-in-google-preferences-file/70104932?noredirect=1#comment123938059_70104932).

Comment: i like this (i had not heard of this powershell option before). I tried the below but it didnt change it back to utf8 and chrome wouldnt take it $json = Get-Content C:\temp\preferences | ConvertFrom-Json

$json.intl.'accept_languages' = 'en-AU'
$json.intl.'selected_languages' = 'en-AU'

$json | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File C:\temp\Preferences -Encoding utf8

Comment: @alokin123 I don't think Chrome likes the file when it has a utf8 BOM included. Try `Set-Content -Path 'C:\temp\Preferences' -Encoding Default`

Comment: Thanks @Theo, by looking at the `master_preferences` file I could see the default encoding was `ANSI`. `-Encoding Default` should work tho haven't tested it.

Comment: thanks for following on with this. I tried setting it to default and as soon as soon as i relaunch chrome, chrome bombs out. I notice that when i crack open the preferences file in notepad its neatly formatted after running the code but before hand its all a jumbled mess.

Comment: @alokin123 you can use the `-Compress` switch to have it in the same format: `$json | ConvertTo-Json -Compress | Out-File...` tho I don't think that's reason why it's not working.

Comment: In similar situations I also found that Chrome is very reluctant to accept changes made from _"the outside"_. It doesn't like tampering and wants to revert to factory settings if it finds the changes were not made by chrome itself... Can't remember what it was I was trying to manipulate at the time, but that may be the case here too..

Comment: Edge will reject IE Mode pages added externally when sync is on, but I haven't yet been able to replicate a similar issue with Chrome. Changes made to Chrome's Preferences file externally have been kept. Additions were also kept, but were relocated. Chrome will, of course, replace the Preferences file if it is corrupt. The answer above will corrupt the file because the `Out-File` line doesn't specify `-Depth` (it needs to be at least 5 and the default is 2) and the encoding has a typo `-Encondig utf8` (it should be `-Encoding utf8`) so it will default to Unicode which will not be accepted.